Debugging apps in Android Studio with HarmonyOs
Does any Android developer have experience with debugging an android app in a Huawei smartphone? I do not consider developing apps for Huawei market. I want to be able to test native apps written in Kotlin in a Huawei device.
Though, this type of question was asked previously, no answer was provided, that's why I needed to ask again
